# I do not understand Recurrence Examples on donald knuth's concrete mathematics last page on chapter 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

**Example 1**: When $n = 100 = (1100100)_2$ our original josephus values $\alpha=1,\beta=-1,\gamma=1$ yield:

Answer:

$
n = \qquad(1\qquad 1\qquad 0\qquad 0\qquad 1 \qquad 0\qquad 0)_2\quad=\quad 100\\
f(n) = \quad(1\qquad 1\qquad {-1}\quad {-1}\quad 1 \quad {-1}\quad {-1})_2\quad\\
 = +64\qquad+32\qquad-16\qquad-8\qquad+4\qquad-2\qquad-1 = 73\\
$

Question:
I understand that $f(1)=1$, But Is there a mathematical explanation to how $f(0)=-1$?
Or was it based on the table in the previous page where $\beta_0 = \beta = -1$ and $\beta_1 = \gamma = 1$ ?

**Example 2**: We are given the recurrence

$\begin{align}
f(1)=34, \\
f(2) = 5, \\
f(3n) = 10f(n) + 76, & \text{for n$\ge$ 1} \\
f(3n+1) = 10f(n) - 2, & \text{for n$\ge$ 1} \\
f(3n+2) = 10f(n) + 8 & \text{for n$\ge$ 1} 
\end{align}$

Compute $f(19)$

Answer: 
$f(19) = f((201)_3) = (5\;76\;-2)_10 = 1258$

Question:

$n = (2 0 1)_3$

We know that f(2) = 5, but how can we mathematically prove that f(0) = 76 and f(1) = -2?

Comment: This question is desperately lacks context; it pretty impossible to figure out what is going on. Please edit it so it is self-contained.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry but i am very new to mathjax, but all of these are all found exactly on page 16 on the book Concrete Mathematics 2nd edition (by Donald Knuth, Ronald L. Graham, Oren Patashnik).

Comment: x @John: So you only want help from people who has that particular book within reach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point in example 2 seems to be that if  $n = 3 m + a$ with $a \in \{0,1,2\}$, the recurrence tells you $f(n) = 10 f(m) + g(a)$, where $g(0) = 76$, $g(1) = -2$ 
and $g(2) = 8$.  So  $f((a_k a_{k-1} \ldots a_0)_3)$ is expressed in terms of
$g(a_0), \ldots, g(a_{k-1})$ and $f(a_k)$.  Thus $19 = (2 0 1)_3$ means
$f(19) = 10 f((20)_3) + g(1) = 10^2 f(2) + 10 g(0) + g(1) = 100 \times 5 + 10 \times 76 -2 = 1258$.